# Importar Bacpac de Azure a SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, azure

Estoy importando un `bacpac` que he generado desde el portal de `Azure` a un `SQL Server 2012` local y obtengo el error que detallo a continuación. ¿Sabéis como puedo solucionarlo para que el paquete se importe correctamente?

### TÍTULO: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

> No se pudo importar el paquete.
>
> Warning SQL72012: El objeto [dd_produccion_Data] existe en el destino, pero no se quitará aunque
> haya seleccionado la casilla 'Generar instrucciones DROP para objetos
> que están en la base de datos de destino pero que no están en el
> proyecto de base de datos'.
>
> Warning SQL72012: El objeto
> [dd_produccion_Log] existe en el destino, pero no se quitará aunque
> haya seleccionado la casilla 'Generar instrucciones DROP para objetos
> que están en la base de datos de destino pero que no están en el
> proyecto de base de datos'.
>
> Error SQL72016: No se pudo asignar una
> nueva página para la base de datos 'dd_produccion' porque el grupo de
> archivos 'PRIMARY' tiene espacio insuficiente en el disco. Quite
> objetos del grupo de archivos, agregue archivos adicionales al grupo
> de archivos o establezca la opción de crecimiento automático para los
> archivos existentes en el grupo de archivos con el fin de crear el
> espacio necesario.
>
> Se terminó la instrucción. Error SQL72045: Error de
> ejecución de script.
>
> El script ejecutado:
>
> /* Los datos se cargan de
> forma masiva en este momento de la ejecución de la implementación
> */
>
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:

> No se pudo asignar una nueva página para la base de datos
> 'dd_produccion' porque el grupo de archivos 'PRIMARY' tiene espacio
> insuficiente en el disco. Quite objetos del grupo de archivos, agregue
> archivos adicionales al grupo de archivos o establezca la opción de
> crecimiento automático para los archivos existentes en el grupo de
> archivos con el fin de crear el espacio necesario. Se terminó la
> instrucción. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1101)
>
> Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.2269&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1101&LinkId=20476

---

Answer (score 1):

El error 1101, nos está diciendo que no tienes espacio el filegroup primary en el archivo que tiene o este ya no puede crecer, verifica que la base de datos no este llena y que tenga un crecimiento adecuado.

También puede haber una relación con este error en el SSDT, en este caso haz una actualización a tus herramientas de data tools.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/786711/upgrade-with-dacpac-fails-when-it-tries-to-drop-system-partitions